# Gravitational coupling of tachyons

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, tachyon

Can General Relativity stress-energy tensor be extended to include contributions from imaginary mass tachyons? what would be the expected gravitational coupling between tachyons and tardions?

Answer (score 8):

Apparently the behavior of tachyons in general relativity has been analyzed, though I don't have information on your second question about couplings to tardyons. P. 127 of J. Richard Gott III's book *Time Travel in Einstein's Universe*, available on google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=MME33bSTCDsC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA127#v=onepage&q&f=false), says:

> A tachyon would have to be accompanied by gravitational waves, just as
>   an airplane exceeding the speed of sound creates a sonic boom. In
>   1974, using a 1972 result found by F. C. Jones plus my own solution to
>   Einstein's field equations for a tachyon in a different context, I
>   found that a tachyon should emit a cone of gravitational radiation
>   that would trail behind it. The emission would cause the tachyon to
>   lose energy and, because of the hypothetical particle's peculiar
>   nature, cause it to accelerate to still higher speeds. In keeping with
>   Jones's insight, the particle's worldline through spacetime is bent
>   like a wide arch. We would see the two sloping sides of the arch as a
>   tachyon and an anti-tachyon approaching each other at just over the
>   speed of light, going faster as they got very close, finally reaching
>   infinite speed as they hit and annihilated each other at the top of
>   the arch. After that, no more tachyon. Because tachyon world lines
>   would bend in this way, tachyons would spend most of the time moving
>   at just barely over light speed.

Based on this description, I suspect that in an asymptotically flat spacetime where we can find a coordinate system that's close to an inertial frame, from the perspective of such a frame the tachyon's worldline would look something like a hyperbola bounded by two sides of some event's past light cone, like the red curves in region IV of the Kruskal-Szekeres diagram [here](http://inspirehep.net/record/1120647/files/fig04.png) (from [this page](http://inspirehep.net/record/1120647/plots)).

The references section on [p. 269](http://books.google.com/books?id=MME33bSTCDsC&lpg=PA269&ots=MtdNzZXN-z&dq=gott%20nuovo%20cimento&pg=PA269#v=onepage&q=tachyons&f=false) indicates this paper by Gott was published in *Astrophysical Journal* 187 (1974): 1. [This page](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/doi/10.1086/152581) shows the title as "A Time-Symmetric Matter, Antimatter, Tachyon Cosmology".

If you want to do further research, [this pdf](http://cds.cern.ch/record/408960/files/9911441.pdf) of a paper from the CERN document server gives "an exact solution of the Einstein-Maxwell equations" involving tachyons, and various papers on tachyons in general relativity are listed in the "references" section of papers like [this one](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/89m0w23g#page-1) and [this one](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1985Ap%26SS.110..393S/0000393.000.html). An interesting point made by the CERN paper is that when analyzing tachyons in general relativity, one doesn't need to make use of any concept of a tachyon "rest mass" so there are no imaginary quantities involved--see section 6 beginning on p. 15.